# Multiple Field search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can we do multiple field search in Elastic search.

for example I want to search subcategory and region, for one field it is working for multiple field search how we have to do.

Below link is working fine, since I am using one field only for search

```
http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/episodes/episode/_search?q=sub_cat_seo_url:english-news&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc
```

but when I try to search multiple field for example sub_cat_seo_url and region it is not working

see this link (not working)

```
http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/episodes/episode/_search?q=sub_cat_seo_url:english-news,region:1&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc

http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/episodes/episode/_search?q=sub_cat_seo_url:english-news&region:1&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc
```

Comment: http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/episodes/episode/_search?q=sub_cat_seo_url:english-news&region:1&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc
Second link is working. It is fetching data.

Comment: @Richa, No, it is not. Try changing the value for region to some non-existing value and it still gives the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation, it should work

See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html

That being said, you can also use the following:

http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/episodes/episode/_search?q=%2Bsub_cat_seo_url%3Aenglish-news+%2Bregion%3A1&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc

NOTE :
The existing mapping makes your field "sub_cat_seo_url" analyzed which is analyzed using `standard analyzer`. Hence, when you are searching for "english-news" it gets tokenized into "english", "news" which results in any document matching either `english or news` to be valid matches. For eg. "telugu-news" is a valid match for your query. Not sure if it is intentional.

In your mapping you need to mark it as "not_analyzed" for exact match.

Note : %2b is decoded as '+' whereas '+' is decoded as ' '

Comment: Hi i had mapped index=not_analyzed, http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/check_episodes/episode/_search?q=+sub_cat_seo_url:headlines+region:15&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc  , but not working (not showing correct data), for search more than one field, when i search sub_cat_seo_url and region

Comment: No, it is not. http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/episodes/episode/_mapping

Comment: Hi @rahulroc, thank,  this is new one we had added $data['mappings']['episode']['properties']['sub_cat_seo_url']['type']='string';
$data['mappings']['episode']['properties']['sub_cat_seo_url']['index']='not_analyzed';$data['mappings']['episode']['properties']['region']['type']='string';
$data['mappings']['episode']['properties']['region']['index']='not_analyzed';                                                 
http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/check_episodes/episode/_search?q=+sub_cat_seo_url:headlines+region:15&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc

Comment: Nice. I checked my solution for this separate index and it works fine. Do you still have any doubts ?

Comment: Hi @rahulroc, thank you for your valuable reply,   in your comments, you had said it is working fine for you, but it is not working, it showing region:2 data when i searched region: 15 only . pls check below link . http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/check_episodes/episode/_search?q=+sub_cat_seo_url:headlines+region:15&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc

Comment: Working Fine. You probably need to dig into encoding and decoding URL to understand. http://34c512ba34534fffdfd12abfd69f2458.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9200/check_episodes/episode/_search?q=%2Bsub_cat_seo_url%3Aheadlines+%2Bregion%3A15&sort=pubdate_timestamp:desc

Comment: %2b is decoded as '+'  whereas '+' is decoded as ' '

Comment: Hi @rahulroc, thanks you. it is working , can you add this 
 
%2b is decoded as '+' whereas '+' is decoded as ' '  in your answer. so if someone find solution easily